# How to remove the focus from mat-datepicker-toggle?

Tags: angular, angular-material, focus, mat-datepicker

I want navigate with tab and instead of navigating to the toggle button, I want to navigate to the editable field. As the image below:
[image]

I tried to find in the documentation an function or directive that disable the focusable from toggle-button, but I don't have success.

Answer (score 1):

Solved: I only add the property binding `[tabIndex]="-1"` in the `mat-datepicker-toggle` element